# VBA - Search for value in one list, in another and paste to adjacent cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA script that searches for each value in one list in another list, and if found, pastes the adjacent value in another range. For some reason it isn't pasting anything but I am not receiving any errors - what am I missing here?

```
Sub tryThis()

Dim lookHere As Range, pasteHere As Range, cell As Range, searchList As Range

Set List1 = Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").End(xlDown))
Set List2 = Range(Range("C1"), Range("C1").End(xlDown))
    
For Each cell In List1
    
    Set found = List2.Find(what:=cell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)

    If Not found Is Nothing Then
        
        cell.Offset(0, 1).Copy Destination:=Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    
    End If
Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: I assume you get something pasted in G1 only?

Comment: ^^^^ `pasteHere` is one cell, `G1`, and it never changes. Most likely you meant: `Destination:=Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Offset(1)`

Comment: Thanks! I need to copy the cell next to it if the value is found. Is this possible using `cell.offset(0,1).Copy`?  For example, if 'hello' is found in a list, I need the cell next to it to be copied